# Don't scroll viewport at the end of iframe scroll Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

The following question is only for mobile devices :

I've got an iframe that pop in absolute over a website. This iFrame must be scrollable, I'm OK with that, but when the scroll in the iframe reach the end, I don't want the viewport to scroll anymore. but it scroll down and reveal the webpage under my frame.

I try to add this on the page that contain my iframe, but doesn't work. If my frame reach the end, if I swipe my finger by touching the frame, the viewport move. if I swipe touching the website, it doesn't...

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Many thanks if you have any Ideas, and sorry for my poor english !

Xavier.

Comment: Hide the content below the iframe?

Comment: yes that's another and maybe better trick thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm Answering my question for those who are searching for this...

I Simply put a position fixed to the webpage that contain my frame, while my frame is popped in...

:)